# How to set height of roster in xmonad withIM layout

Tags: haskell, layout, xmonad, profanity

I am using the withIM layout in xmonad and I am using conky and dzen, which results in the roster overlaying the conky/dzen bar, while other windows are not overlapping. I am using `profanity` within `st` as IM.

I searched a while for a solution to change the height, but I didn't find anything useful. My layout configuration looks like this:

```
  --
  -- Layouts
  --

  sPx = 1

  verticalLayout = spacing sPx $ avoidStruts $ reflectHoriz $ Tall 1 0.03 0.5
  verticalLayoutLargeScreen = spacing sPx $ avoidStruts $ ThreeCol 1 0.03 0.5
  horizontalLayout = spacing sPx $ avoidStruts $ Mirror $ Tall 1 0.03 0.5
  webdevLayout = spacing sPx $ avoidStruts $ Tall 1 0.03 0.63
  fullscreenLayout = noBorders $ fullscreenFull $ Full

  myLayout =
      onWorkspace "2:web" (webdevLayout ||| fullscreenLayout) $ reflectHoriz $
                      (withIM (3%7) (ClassName "Profanity")
                      (verticalLayoutLargeScreen ||| Grid ||| Full |||
                      verticalLayout ||| horizontalLayout ||| fullscreenLayout))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried pulling the `avoidStruts` further out; something along these lines:

```
  verticalLayout = spacing sPx $ reflectHoriz $ Tall 1 0.03 0.5
  verticalLayoutLargeScreen = spacing sPx $ ThreeCol 1 0.03 0.5
  horizontalLayout = spacing sPx $ Mirror $ Tall 1 0.03 0.5
  webdevLayout = spacing sPx $ Tall 1 0.03 0.63
  fullscreenLayout = noBorders $ fullscreenFull $ Full

  myLayout =
      onWorkspace "2:web" (webdevLayout ||| fullscreenLayout) $
      avoidStruts $
      reflectHoriz $
      withIM (3%7) (ClassName "Profanity") $
          verticalLayoutLargeScreen |||
          Grid |||
          Full |||
          verticalLayout |||
          horizontalLayout |||
          fullscreenLayout
```